# I cannot see the Badge's icon and color in my React.js project

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDUlS.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {

    UncontrolledDropdown,
    DropdownToggle,
    DropdownMenu,
    DropdownItem,
    Badge,
} from 'reactstrap';

export default class CartSummary extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                    <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                        Cart - {this.props.cart.length}
                    </DropdownToggle>
                    <DropdownMenu right>
                        {
                            this.props.cart.map(cartItem => (
                                <DropdownItem key={cartItem.product.id}>
                                    {cartItem.product.productName}
                                    <Badge color="success">{cartItem.quantity}</Badge>
                                </DropdownItem>
                            ))
                        }
```

Comment: Do you get the correct `cartItem.quantity`? If you replace `{cartItem.quantity}` with just `Test`, does the error persist?

Comment: when I move the cursor over the products in the cart, I can see the quantities but it doesn't seem clearly so I want them to seem in the color I declared in badge